# How to pass static matrix in a function with poiners in C?

Tags: c, matrix, multidimensional-array, parameter-passing

I need to optimize by memory program, so I decided to use pointers with static matrix, but i I don't know much about pointers in C, and the program doesn't work(in VS program throws exceptions)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Sumofsum(int **matrix, int size) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
            sum += matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

void SumofSumOut(int sum) {
    printf("Sum of sums of elements in those rows: %d\n", sum);
}

int main() {
    int matrix[5][5] =
            {
                    {21,8, 3, 4, 5},
                    {1, 3, 5, 7, 9},
                    {2, 4, 6, 8, 9},
                    {1, 3, 4, 5, 7},
                    {3, 3, 3, 3,11}
            };
    int sum, size = 5;
    sum = Sumofsum(matrix, size);
    SumofSumOut(sum);
    return 0;
}
```

i tried to use (*matrix)[5], but it's not what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int **matrix` indicates a pointer to pointer. It's what `int *matrix[]` would degrade into.

You don't have an array of pointers.

---

Treat the array as 1d:

```c
int sum_of_sum( int *matrix, int size ) {
    int sum = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < size; ++i ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < size; ++j ) {
            sum += matrix[ i * size + j ];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

sum_of_sum( &matrix[0][0], size )
```

---

Pass a pointer to the first row.

```c
int sum_of_sum( int size, int (*matrix)[ size ] ) {
    int sum = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < size; ++i ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < size; ++j ) {
            sum += matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

sum_of_sum( size, matrix );
```

---

Pass a pointer to the array.

```c
int sum_of_sum( int size, int (*matrix)[ size ][ size ] ) {
    int sum = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < size; ++i ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < size; ++j ) {
            sum += matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}


sum_of_sum( size, &matrix );
```

Comment: Also: Actually use a 1d array.

Comment: will be `int sum_of_sum( int size, int (*matrix)[ size ] )` consume less memory than `int sum_of_sum(int size, int matrix[size][size])`?

Comment: No. As a parameter, `int matrix[size][size]` means `int matrix[][size]`. And as a parameter, that means `int (*matrix)[size]`: A pointer to an array of `size` `int`s. All three are 100% equivalent.

Comment: In fact, every solution presented uses exactly the same amount of memory (one pointer). The only difference is the type of the pointer. Even the address is the same in all cases. And that's not it. An optimizing compiler will surely generate exactly the same code for each of the solutions. This applies to actually using a 1d array (not shown) too.  `int matrix[5][5]` takes exactly the same amount of memory as `int matrix[5*5]`.